# Nested innerText multiple elements same class

Tags: javascript

Just starting to understand a bit about javascript, but I could use some help with the following challenge. I am trying to get the innerText from an element for which multiple classes are present on the same page with the same name. The page I am referring to contains four list items all with the class being 'item-details'. The four list items all have innerText which I am trying to return with a javascript statement. The codebase looks like this:

```
<ul class="item-details">
<li><span class="item-detail"><i class="fa fa-left fa-tags"></i><a href="https://www.test.com/all-items/?category=test" title="tags">Tags</a></span></li>
<li><span class="item-detail"><i class="fa fa-left fa-calendar"></i>26 march 2019</span></li>
<li><span class="item-detail"><strong>Level</strong>: Level 5</span></li>
<li><span class="item-detail"><strong>Source</strong>: <a href="https://www.testsource.com/" title="Test Source" target="_blank">Test Source</a></span></li>
```

I expect four seperate pieces of javascript code with a return statement for the innerText for one of the four list items. I need four seperate pieces of code, because I need to define each page level variable in a different platform, Google Tag Manager, in a seperate custom javascript variable. Hence, I am looking for four pieces of javascript, which simply return the innerText from each list element. Hence I expect the following values to be returned looking at the sample code I have provided:
- Tags
- 26 march 2019
- : Level 5
- Test Source

Pure javascript, no jQuery, would be appreciated!

Hope someone is able to educate me!

If I have overlooked a previously asked question on this forum with a possible relevant answer, you are more than welcome to push me in that direction.

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service. If you want help, show what you have tried first.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = document.getElementsByClassName('item-detail');

result.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element.innerText)
});
```